# SCons less verbose?

Tags: scons

I want to remove from the SCons log the long compiling/linking commands.

I followed what is written on this page :
[What do you do to make compiler lines shorter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890142/what-do-you-do-to-make-compiler-lines-shorter)

Here is exactly what I did :

```
AddOption("--verbose", action="store_true",
           dest="verbose_flag", default=False, help="verbose output")
if not GetOption("verbose_flag"):
        print 'test'
        env['CXXCOMSTR'] = "----- Compiling test ------"
        env['LINKCOMSTR'] = "Linking $TARGET"
print env.Dump()

env.SharedLibrary(..
```

SCons goes in the if ('test' is printed), and CXXCOMSTR and LINKCOMSTR are updated (checked with Dump()).

But it seems that SCOns just doesn't care : it still prints the full g++ commands.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

`CXXCOMSTR` and `LINKCOMSTR` are used for static objects, you are building shared ones. Set `SHCXXCOMSTR` and `SHLINKCOMSTR`.

Comment: Hmmm... It is OK for gcc, but with Visual Studio remains two lines giving the Visual Studio version and a copyright...

Comment: Add `/nologo` to compiler and linker flags.

Comment: there is no way to remove that line, cl.exe always print its source file, and no flag can turn it off